# How to POST a nested JSON using Alamofire?

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I want to use Alamofire(V3.5.1), and I am using Swift(V2.3). the JSON I want to post is this.

```
{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "image": {
        "dataType": 50,
        "dataValue": "base64_image_string"
      },
      "configure": {
        "dataType": 50,
        "dataValue": "{\"side\":\"face\"}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And I try to make the `Alamofire` parameters like this

```
    let parameters : [String: AnyObject] = [
        "inputs" : [
        [ "image":[
            "dataType":50,
            "dataValue":(base64String)
            ],
            "configure":[
            "dataTpye":50,
                "dataValue": ["side" :"face"]
            ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

But the result I get is this. `FAILURE: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0.`

**Q1:How can I POST a correct nested json in the body?**

EDIT：I tried to use @Zonily Jame's way to create the JSON Object, but it failed. Here's my code:

```
        let imageData:[String:AnyObject] = ["dataType":50, "dataValue":"string"]
    let configureData:[String:AnyObject] = ["dataType":50, "dataValue":"{\"side\":\"face\"}"]
    let inputsData:[String:AnyObject] = ["image":dictToJSON(imageData) , "configure":dictToJSON(configureData)]
    let parameters:[String:AnyObject] = ["inputs":dictToJSON(inputsData)]
```

and I printed the `parameters` variable which looked like this:

```
["inputs": {
    configure =     {
        dataType = 50;
        dataValue =         {
            side = face;
        };
    };
    image =     {
        dataType = 50;
        dataValue = "";
    };
}]
```

Somehow the syntax is still incorrect. And I also tried to use `dictToJSON()` on the variable `configureData`, I still got the same result.

---

The expected response should be

```
  {
  "outputs": [
    {
      "outputLabel": "ocr_id",
      "outputMulti": {},
      "outputValue": {
        "dataType": 50,
        "dataValue": "{\"address\": \"string\", \"config_str\" : \"{\"side\":\"face\"}\", \"name\" : \"Jack\",\"num\" : \"1234567890\", \"success\" : true}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

EDIT: This is the API's document about how to phrase response but in JAVA

```
try {
            JSONObject resultObj = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray outputArray = resultObj.getJSONArray("outputs");
            String output = outputArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("outputValue").getString("dataValue"); 
            JSONObject out = new JSONObject(output);
            if (out.getBoolean("success")) {
                String addr = out.getString("address"); 
                String name = out.getString("name"); 
                String num = out.getString("num"); 
                System.out.printf(" name : %s \n num : %s\n address : %s\n", name, num, addr);
            } else {
                System.out.println("predict error");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and request code

```
public static JSONObject getParam(int type, JSONObject dataValue) {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            obj.put("dataType", type);
            obj.put("dataValue", dataValue);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return obj;
    }


    public static JSONObject getParam(int type, String dataValue) {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            obj.put("dataType", type);
            obj.put("dataValue", dataValue);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return obj;
    }

        JSONObject requestObj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            JSONObject configObj = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            JSONArray inputArray = new JSONArray();
            configObj.put("side", configStr);
            obj.put("image", getParam(50, imgBase64));
            obj.put("configure", getParam(50, configObj.toString()));
            inputArray.put(obj);
            requestObj.put("inputs", inputArray);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String body = requestObj.toString();
```

NOTE:`imgBase64`is a String.

**Q2:How can I analyse this kind of JSON? I just want the `dataValue`,Thanks**

Comment: Can you post your Alamofire codes? **note:** you can hide the url if necessary mate

Comment: The parameters you got was correct imo, in your `api` are you sure the server is made to accept `application/json` types of parameters? I don't get what you mean after the "And I prospective to get a response" could you rephrase?

Comment: @ZonilyJame I mean the server will give me this response, this is a correct example in the API's Document.And I  use this Alamofire method `     Alamofire.request(.POST,
                          url,
                          parameters: parameters,
                          encoding: .JSON,
            headers: headers).responseJSON `

Comment: I think in your `configureData` variable the key "dataValue" shouldn't use dictToJSON because it might be a `String` field in your db, as seen on the server reply you're expecting to have

Comment: the code should look pretty much like this if I'm correct `let imageData:[String:AnyObject] = ["dataType":50,
                                            "dataValue":"string"]
    let configureData:[String:AnyObject] = ["dataType":50,
                                                "dataValue":"{\"side\":\"face\"}"]
    let inputsData:[String:AnyObject] = ["image":dictToJSON(imageData) ,
                                             "configure":dicoToJSON(configureData)]
        
    let parameters:[String:AnyObject] = ["inputs":dictToJSON(inputsData)]`

Comment: Unfortunately, don't have any change, but the 'dataValue' have correct value. I will EDIT my question and ADD the API's document example about phase response, but it's JAVA code.Thank again.

Comment: it's not the response that we should see but what we should send bro.

Comment: Already add code :)

Comment: add your swift code too

Comment: I have no more swift code, just change the 'dataValue' to a String

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is to first convert your `Dictionaries/Arrays` inside your `Super Dictionary` to a JSON object

For example let's make an object

```
let object = [
    "franchise": [
        "name": "Marvel",
        "movies": ["Doctor Strange", "Iron Man", "Spider Man"]
    ]
]
```

For this to work we need to separate these objects, which would roughly look like this (just did this for readability)

```
let movies:[String] = ["Doctor Strange", "Iron Man", "Spider Man"]

let franchiseDetails:[String:AnyObject] = [
  "name": "Marvel",
    "movies": movies
]
let franchise:[String:AnyObject] = [
    "franchise": franchiseDetails
]
```

And then just convert them to a JSON Object by using `NSJSONSerialization` by using these functions

```
func dictToJSON(dict:[String: AnyObject]) -> AnyObject {
    let jsonData = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: .PrettyPrinted)
    let decoded = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: [])
    return decoded
}

func arrayToJSON(array:[String]) -> AnyObject {
    let jsonData = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(array, options: .PrettyPrinted)
    let decoded = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: [])
    return decoded
}


let newObject = [
    "franchise": dictToJSON([
        "name": "Marvel",
        "movies": arrayToJSON(["Doctor Strange", "Iron Man", "Spider Man"])
    ])
]
```

You can now use this object in your Alamofire Request

Comment: Thanks for your answer,it's very useful. And I have another question is how to add this string to the dictionary? `"dataValue": "{\"side\":\"face\"}" ` I'm very confused.

Comment: Is that supposed to be a dictionary in a dictionary?

Comment: I'm not sure. This is a API request example

Comment: I have a feeling that that's a `Dictionary` in a `Dictionary`. Basically what you should do is to convert the inner `Dictionary` to a JSON object like what I did in my answer. so it would look like this ["dataValue": dictToJSON(["side":"face"])]

Comment: This is because Alamofire is accepting `[String: AnyObject]`, which is a `Dictionary` ,values on their parameters

Comment: Basically what happens on Alamofire is that they only convert the `Main DIctionary` you pass into JSON format, and on the succeeding `Sub Dictionaries` They just pass that like a String object **based on my understanding of their library**

Comment: Thanks I'll try it :)

Comment: sorry for the late response mate, was out of connection for a while, could you add your alamofire code to the question?

Comment: I add my Alamofire code, but I think it's not very useful

Comment: I made a mistake, this part `"dataValue": "{\"side\":\"face\"}"` where `"{\"side\":\"face\"}"` is a String shouldn't use `dictToJSON` because it's supposed to be a String like how your question above suggested

Comment: Yes, you're right, this part `"{\"side\":\"face\"}"` is correct.But why my parameters have `equal mark ` and  `colon`? I think it's not a truly  json. And I tried to modified this part ` let inputsData:[String:AnyObject] = ["image":dictToJSON(imageData) ,"configure":dictToJSON(configureData)]`
        `let parameters:[String:AnyObject] = ["inputs":dictToJSON(inputsData)]` Don't have any change

Comment: No it is JSON believe me. it just looks that way because of how iOS parses it to be printed but it is on JSON format `application/json` to be precise

Comment: @Shucheng could you please post your parameters final state?

Answer (score 1):

you can give dictionary type of nested dictionaries or you can make separate dictionary  for each key which requires dictionary.
like  [AnyObject: AnyObject] .

For Analysis of key  you can convert the response in dictionary form  and use its method valueforKeyPath

Comment: but `Alamofire.request` need a  parameters as [String:AnyObject],so I can't make my body as a [AnyObject: AnyObject].And I know how to analysis a normal json,but I don't know how to analysis nest json like `"dataValue": "{\"address\": \"string\", \"config_str\" : \"{\"side\":\"face\"}\", \"name\" : \"Jack\",\"num\" : \"1234567890\", \"success\" : true}"`  Can you help me?

Comment: if let jsonResult = response as? NSDictionary {
                        let OrderObjectIds = jsonResult.value(forKeyPath: "result.objectId")}

Comment: use "outputs.outputValue.dataValue" in in keyPath

Comment: you can use [AnyObject:AnyObject] for  image  and configure dictionary

Comment: let parameters:[String:AnyObject] = ["className": ApiConstants.KClassOrder,"include":["medicine","_User"] ,"data":data].           and data  dictionary  can be like. var data : [[String:AnyObject]] = [
            [ "column" : "user" as AnyObject, "value" : userObjectId as AnyObject,"class" : "_User" as AnyObject]]

Comment: um..can you use your syntax write to me for my case？